# get and save values from one-to-many relationship and use in javascript with Laravel

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, one-to-many

Controller code is:

```
$payments = array();
        $pays = User::find($userid);
        foreach ($pays->payments as $pay) {
        $payments = $pay->payment;
        }
```

it gives output as 18000, 19000, 9000 as stored in array.
I'm confused how to pas these values to my blade file and use in the javascript.
I'm getting only the last values of the array when using in JS.

Comment: save it in an hidden input and then using jquery use it

Comment: @Shoaib Akhtar: Means you need only last value of array right?

Comment: Why not just return the value of `$pays` to blade ?

Comment: no dear i need to get all three values and then use them all in the populated table one after another.

Comment: public function myAccount(User $user)
    {
$pays = User::find($userid);
        foreach ($pays->payments as $pay) {
        $payments = $pay->payment;
        }
return view('user_account', compact('payments')
}
its the full code that will then needs to be fetched in the <script> and using all values of payments it will through it into the custom generated table.

Comment: @C2486 i have tried to use $pay to blade
foreach($pays->payments as $ss)
<tr>
<td>{{$ss->payment}}</td>
</tr>
endforeach
this works fine but doesn't work in the script tag for me

Comment: to make it work in javascript you can use `json_encode` in javascript and `JSON.parse()` to decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting value of `$payments`  use `[]` to add in array

```
  $payments = array();
  $pays = User::find($userid);
  foreach ($pays->payments as $pay) {
    $payments[] = $pay->payment;
  }
  return view('myview_name',compact('payments'))
```

In laravel blade

```
@foreach($payments as $payment) 
   <tr> <td>{{$payment}}</td> </tr> 
@endforeach
```

In javascript you can `json_encode` and `JSON.parse` to decode it

```
var payments = <?php echo json_encode($payments) ?>;
console.log(payments);
```

Comment: If you omit the wrapping `"` in the js variable you can skip the `JSON.parse` since JSON encoded arrays are valid JS syntax

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
$payments = array();
$pays = User::find($userid);
foreach ($pays->payments as $pay) {
    $payments[] = $pay->payment;
}
```

Or simpler:

```
$payments = $pays->payments->pluck("payment");
```

And then pass it to the view via e.g.

```
return view('view.name', compact('payments'));
```

You can then use it in the view as an array.

If you want to pass it into a JS variable you can use:

```
<script>
       var payments = {!! json_encode($payments) !!};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="hidden" id="data" value="{{ $payments }}">
```

In script section

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    data = $('#data').val();
    // Myabe u will need to parse the same.
    // And then use it accordingly
});
```

**UPDATE**
Return the array in json format and use `$.parseJSON(data);` to retrieve in js.